# Is Butterknife.findById() better than findViewById()?

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid, butterknife

Does using `ButterKnife.findById()` offer any sort of performance increase over using `findViewById()`? I'm guessing no--and this it's made for simplification of code only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/src/main/java/butterknife/ButterKnife.java) it just does the type cast for you. So it's cleaner, but no less performant

```
return (T) view.findViewById(id);
```

Comment: I didn't think to look there for some reason--that was dumb of me. Thank you.